# How can I refresh a List of Database Objects in Grails?

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

[Grails docu](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/refresh.html) says that refreshing an object from the database can be done by:

```
def book = Book.get(1)

book.refresh()
```

How can I refresh a list of objects?

```
def books = Book.getAll()
```

Can I do the following?

```
books.refresh()
```

The problem is that somewhere I get books from a search a result so I have to get the full data set from the database.

Comment: Its depend on requirement that how you want to use it on view.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course loop over the list:

```
def books = Book.getAll()
books.each {
    it.refresh()
}
```

but why not just get the list again? It seems that would be equivalent and more efficient.

Comment: I updated my question. Problem is that I get the data incomplete from a search. I there am more efficient way of reloading?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Play with fetch mode with additional info. 
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#fetching

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be done in this way:

```
books*.refresh()
```